# Trying to increase a Cubes scale in Unity and then decrease when it reaches a certain number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is how I'm going about it:

```
if(transform.localScale.x > 7)
{
    for(int i = 7; i > 1; i--)
    {
        transform.localScale -= new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
else
{
    transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

The else statement is executed to increase the scale and when it reaches 7 the if statement should decrease it back to 1 thanks to the for loop which should run for 6 iterations and decrease the scale 6 times. But only the else part works properly when the scale reaches 7 it just gets decreased to 6 and then back to 7 in a second. It doesn't go all the way down to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that your entire `for` loop will be executed immediately within one single frame? and you multiply that by `Time.deltaTime` which assuming 60 frames per second would be a value around `0.0166666666...`.

So what you are ding in a loop basically just equals doing

```
transform.localScale -= Vector3.one * 6 * 0.017f;
```

Right in the next frame you might already again be lower than `7` => you land in the `else` case and again increase the scale.

So in the next frame it will already decrease it again etc

---

From what I understand is you rather want kind of a pin pong effect between two scales.

I would rather use something like

```
// adjust via the Inspector
public float speed = 1;
public float amplitude = 7f;

private Vector3 originalScale;
private float timePassed;

private void Start()
{
    originalScale = transform.localScale;
}

private void Update()
{
    timePassed += Time.deltaTime * speed;

    // see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html
    transform.localScale = originalScale * (1 + Mathf.PingPong(timePassed, amplitude - 1));
    // or with ease-in and ease-out
    //transform.localScale = originalScale * (1 + (amplitude - 1) * Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, Mathf.PingPong(timePassed, 1)));
}
```

Where [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html)

> returns a value that will increment and decrement between the value 0 and length.

---

Or if you actually need a different increase and decrease duration I would rather suggest a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
// adjust via the Inspector
public float increaseDuration = 1f;
public float decreaseDuration = 7f;

public float amplitude = 7f;

private IEnuemerator Start()
{
    var originalScale = transform.localScale;
    var maxScale = originalScale * amplitude;

    while(true)
    {
        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < increaseDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            var factor = timePassed / increaseDuration;
            // optinal add ease-in and ease-out
            //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, maxScale, factor);

            yield return null;
        }

        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < decreaseDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            var factor = timePassed / decreaseDuration;
            // optinal add ease-in and ease-out
            //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(maxScale, originalScale, factor);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an other variable like:

```
public bool isDecreasing=false;

if(!isDecreasing && transform.localScale.x > 7)
{
   isDecreasing=true
}else if(isDecreasing&&transform.localScale.x==1)
{
   isDecreasing=false
}

if(isDecreasing)
{
   transform.localScale -= new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime;
}else
{
   transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: This will still execute the entire loop in a single frame though so most probably kin of end up in the same behavior